# MessageBox is not displayed if it called from a method of a class in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, class, methods, messagebox

I have a PowerShell function which works fine if I use a message box to provide some feedback to the user. I want to add the function to a class though. The class method works fine except this line of code:

```
[system.windows.forms.messagebox]::show("The folder path does contain the right parameters.")
```

It keeps giving me the error:

```
Unable to find type: [System.Windows.Forms.Messagebox]
```

I have tried everything I could find on the Internet. I created a really simple class as shown below which will display the message box in ISE, but it doesn't show the message box if I run it in a PowerShell window. I just don't have the knowledge to figure out why.

```
class test {
    [void]ok() {
        Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.Windows.Form"
        [void][System.Windows.Forms.Messagebox]::Show("This works in ISE but not powershell window")
    }
}

$e = [test]::new()
$e.ok()
```

I am sure there is a simple answer to this, but I don't know what it is.

Comment: What happens when you use `[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Form")` instead?

Comment: It's System.Windows.Form**s**, not System.Windows.Form

Comment: Thanks for that missing the S was a typo I had to retype the script.  It definately says System.Windows.Forms.  Also [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") made no improvements.  I did some more testing and the scrips works only in Powershell (x86) when run as Administrator.  It won't run when I right click it and Run with Powershell or from any other Powershell command window.  I will edit the question to seek further clarification.

Comment: @DanielGREEN - Please don't edit a question to make answers obsolete. If you have an update add it to the end of the existing question. If you're asking something new the ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

I have done some testing and have identified that this script is only running when I call the script in a command window from Powershell (x86) run as Administrator.  When I call the script from any other version of Powershell including just right clicking the script and telling it to run in powershell it gives me the error:

Unable to find type [System.Windows.Forms.Messagebox]

```
class test {

[void]ok() {

 Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.Windows.Forms"
 [void][System.Windows.Forms.Messagebox]::Show("This works in ISE but not powershell window")
}
}

$e = [test]::new()
$e.ok()
```

However, when I turn this into a function as per below it works fine.

```
function test {

 Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.Windows.Forms"
 [void][System.Windows.Forms.Messagebox]::Show("This works in ISE but not powershell window")
}

test
```

Can anyone please shed light on what is causing this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Oh yes, you are right, the answer is really simple.  The assembly you want to load is known as "System.Windows.Form**s**"

Have a nice weekend!

Comment: Sorry that was a typo I have done some more testing and edited my question accordingly.